# Set value of bind:group-value in combination with dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am currently trying to create a wizard-like succession of questions in svelte. For this I use a component that gets a question as a parameter and builds a list of radio items (simplified):

```
<Question question="{{ activeQuestion }}"></Question>
```

Inside the component following code builds the form element:

```
{{#each question.options as option}}
  <li class="question-section__option">
    <input type='radio' bind:group='selected' value='{{ option.value }}'>
    <label>{{ option.label }}</label>
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

in `oncreate` I observe the question parameter and initialize and try to set a default value based on answers from my store:

```
oncreate() {
  this.observe('question', question => {
    const answers = this.store.get('answers');

    if (answers[question.id]) {
      this.set({
        selected: answers[question.id]
      });
    }
  })
},
```

Setting the `selected` value stops working after the "question" property of the component changed once. It doesn't seem to matter if it is set by observing or just in a regular onclick-event.

It would be great if someone has an idea what I did wrong or point me in the right direction!

Comment: Any chance you could put together a small repro to help us debug? (It may be a problem in Svelte itself, rather than anything you're doing wrong.) Here's how to add a store to a component in the REPL: https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.51.1&gist=025849b7059b28732b6a6f513877d40b

Comment: I did my best to recreate the scenario as a repl here: https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.53.0&gist=820f141fcb3a195bf05e8f309f3c536f

Sure enough, I wasn't able to reproduce this in the REPL - it seemed to work perfectly. So I recreated my example locally using a webpack build setup based on your examples - same problem again.

Comment: I also created a github repo and setup which demonstrates the problem: https://github.com/archnode/svelte-test

At this point: Thank you very much for your work on svelte and your fast reply!

Comment: Made a similar mockup in v3, seeing issues with binding `checked` too. https://svelte.dev/repl/04a89d481e9d4b27969747cf3a0e5913?version=3.4.2

Comment: Did not use "keyed each", so svelte did not distinguish radio buttons. https://svelte.dev/tutorial/keyed-each-blocks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified wizard of questions in Svelte v3:

```
<script>
    let questions = [{
        title: "First question",
        id: 'first',
        options: [{
            title: "Option 1",
            value: "option1"
        }, {
            title: "Option 2",
            value: "option2"
        }]
    }, {
        title: "Second question",
        id: 'second',
        options: [{
            title: "Option 3",
            value: "option3"
        }, {
            title: "Option 4",
            value: "option4"
        }]
    }];
    let activeQuestion = 0;
    $: question = questions[activeQuestion];
    function dec() {
        if (activeQuestion === 0) { return }
        activeQuestion -= 1
    }
    function inc() {
        if (activeQuestion === (questions.length - 1)) { return }
        activeQuestion += 1
    }
    let answers = {}
</script>

<h1>{question.title}!</h1>
{#each question.options as option (option.value)}
    <label on:click>
        <input type=radio 
                     name={question.id} 
                     value={option.value}
                     on:change={() => answers[question.id] = option.value}
                     checked={answers[question.id] == option.value}
                     /> 
        {option.title}
    </label>
{/each}

<button on:click={dec}>previous</button>
<button on:click={inc}>next</button>
```

REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/2de246c59cb346ca8cb7244749afe8ea?version=3

It should translate well to stores too. Note the each-loop which uses `(option.value)` as a key, such that svelte can distinguish radio inputs from each other. Read more about [keyed each loops in the documentation](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/keyed-each-blocks).